# Please help offsetting a coordinate in a non-linear way

Tags: java, android, function, math, algebra

Suppose you have a coordinate that can be anywhere from 0.0 to 1.0 ( see blue line ), but I need to offset it as the red line.

I.e. when it is 0.75 it should be 0.75 + offsetValue, when it is 0.25 it should be 0.25 - offsetValue.
[image]

How would you do that?
Thanks!

Comment: You're talking about 1D coordinates, but you supply an illustration that seems to belong in the 2D setting. Could you clarify what you mean? In what space are you working?

Comment: Moreover, your drawing sort of indicates a sine-like "offset", but your text does not at all make this clear.

Comment: Hehe, you rotated the drawing, but its still 2d :)

Comment: anyway, you could take any point on that line and put a small circle around it, and then you move along that circle from 0 to 360 degrees as you move the point in the line from 0.0 to 1.0. that would give a similar shape to the one you have drawn, and shouldn't be to hard to implement.

Comment: :) i have a 1-d coordinate which is from 0.0 to 1.0   , what I need is to offset it by a certain value when it is 0.25 and 0.75 in a smooth fashion, like the red line in the drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use something like `-sin(blue_value * 2 * PI)` or `sin(-1 * blue_value * 2 * PI)`

What you want is a negative sine curve from 0-2PI.

Check [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28-x%29)